# Custom styling progress bar in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a progress bar and i want to style it away from default.

I tried bit of things but it didn't work as I expected.

I want to change the background color and border radius of the progress bar.

When I set the background color, it changes from the default blue to green color and not to the color I set.

```
<progress class="amount-progress" value="60500" max="120000">70 %</progress>
```

You can see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/84et5rp3/).

When i set the `background-color` the color changes from blue to green which has to change to a different blue.

And i want the progress bar to have a smooth edge.

I did set `border-radius` but this also didn't work out.

```
.amount-progress {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: -11.5%;
  height: 22px;
  background-color: #0091EA;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the color of HTML5 progress bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21476748/how-to-change-the-color-of-html5-progress-bar)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You have to work with the kit of HTML5 progress bar.These are currently the entire selectors for styling HTML5 progress bar:

```
progress {
  /* style rules */
}
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  /* style rules */
}
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  /* style rules */
}
progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  /* style rules */
}
```

so :

```css
progress {
  border-radius: 7px; 
  width: 80%;
  height: 22px;
  margin-left: -11.5%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.2 );
}
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 7px;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 3px rgba( 255, 0, 0, 0.8 );
}
progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  /* style rules */
}
```

```html
<progress value="3333" max="10000">33%</progress>
```

One thing to keep in mind is that there are two types of progress bars: **indeterminate** and **determinate**. If you use the above you will be changing the style for both. If you only want to change the style for a determinate bar you can do the below. This is useful if you want to style the indeterminate progress bar different, for example with a rounded spinner or anything like that.

```css
progress {
    display: block;
}

    /* Determinate: */

    progress[value] {
      /* style rules */
    }
    progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
      /* style rules */
    }
    progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
      /* style rules */
    }
    progress[value]::-moz-progress-bar {
      /* style rules */
    }

    /* Indeterminate: */

    progress:not([value]) {
      /* style rules */
    }
    progress:not([value])::-webkit-progress-bar {
      /* style rules */
    }
    progress:not([value])::-webkit-progress-value {
      /* style rules */
    }
    progress:not([value])::-moz-progress-bar {
      /* style rules */
    }
```

```html
<p>Determinate:</p>

<progress value="66" max="100">Determinate</progress>

<p>Indeterminate:</p>

<progress>Indeterminate</progress>
```

Comment: How do you change the color green?

Comment: `progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
      background-color: your-color-choice;
    }`

Comment: One important thing to note, is that browsers ignore rules they do not recognise, so keep the declarations for different browsers separate.

Comment: In order for this to work in Safari, I had to use `-webkit-appearance: none;` as was suggested in the question mentioned in [caramba's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42290719/custom-styling-progress-bar-in-css/42292476#comment71737469_42290719).